# what exactly does the Gmail API push notification rate limit mean?

Tags: gmail-api

I'm building a messaging system for GCP-hosted platform and plan to use Gmail as a backing system. Users can write their messages through our system which will invoke Gmail API to send emails to other recipients. When someone responds, Gmail API sends a push notification and our system in turn notifies a used.

As I expect high spikes of user activity, the limitation of 1 notification per second (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push):

> Each Gmail user being watched has a maximum notification rate of 1 event/sec. Any user notifications above that rate will be dropped.

doesn't seem to work for me. But to be sure I want to understand what does it exactly mean.

In particular:
what will happen if my mailbox receive 100 emails in a second? Will Gmail generate a single notification which will include all 100 messages? Or there will be several notifications generated which will eventually notify me about all messages? Or due to high messages rate and the above-mentioned limit of 1 notification per second I will receive a single notification for the first message and the rest 99 will not be pushed to my backend?

Answer (score 0):

What the documentation tells you is that, if 100 notifications appear on the same user on gmail at the same time, the first notification would come thru, then the other 99 would be dropped.

However, there is a way to recover changes by using history events, this is referred to as `sync`  and there are multiple ways to do this. I suggest you read up on the [Partial Synchronization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync#partial_synchronization) guide.

The documentation also offers some advice on how you should architect your code to deal with this, specially in the [Reliability section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#reliability).